# Cobian Backup: Incorrect parameter error

Tags: backup, logging

I have some Cobian Backup tasks to copy a file to an external hard drive. To prevent it from being compromised, the drive will not be mounted until the task is launched. We use the following AutoHotkey script:

```
RunAs, Administrator, adminpassword
Run, cmd.exe /C "C:\Folder\MontaSiempreX.bat"
RunAs
Exit
```

MontaSiempreX.bat just mounts the unit called *COPIASALFA* on **X** letter using [this](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/drivetools_e.html) tools:

```
@echo off

set NUEVA=X:
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr "COPIASALFA"') do @set ANTIGUA=%%a
set "ANTIGUA=%ANTIGUA%:"

if "%ANTIGUA%" == ":" (LoadMedia.exe %NUEVA%) else (ReMount.exe %ANTIGUA% %NUEVA%)

ping localhost -n 6 > nul
```

After the backup is done, the following script is launched as an Administrator (using a new AutoHotkey script and RunAs command as before):

```
@echo off

EjectMedia.exe X -o
```

The problem is that the Cobian task sometimes fails. When it does, the log will show the following error:

> ERR 2016-01-21 04:00 No se pudo copiar el fichero
>   "C:\COPIAS\Jueves\Jueves.zip": **El parámetro no es correcto**

Can someone help me? Jueves.zip is the source file... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was simple to fix. I just had to edit the AutoHotkey script:

```
RunAs, Administrator, adminpassword
Run, cmd.exe /C "C:\Folder\MontaSiempreX.bat"
RunAs
Sleep 5000 <--- FIX!
Exit
```

Then, ping instruction was removed.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the OP's problem, other than being a possible cause for the "parameter is incorrect" error.

If the file size is greater than 4GB, and the backup media is formatted with FAT32, then this error occurs.

Possible solutions include converting the backup media to NTFS or exFAT. But be aware of possible consequences if the disk is to be used with other systems. For example, Mac OS X can read NTFS disks, but not write them, at least not without adding a driver.